# Nested Relations in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am following the url:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

This is my model:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('album', 'order')
        ordering = ['order']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%d: %s' % (self.order, self.title)
```

This is my serializer:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration')

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

I am expecting result like this :

```
{
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
    'tracks': [
        {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
        {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
        {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
        ...
    ],
}
```

But i am not getting the tracks:

```
{
    "album_name": "The Grey Album",
    "artist": "Danger Mouse",
    "tracks": []
}
```

Comment: by seeing your code it should work. is there any error is console

Comment: I think you need the `view_name` parameter: `TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, view_name=<your-view-name>)`

Comment: To display an empty list for `tracks` attribute and no errors, your code should be working. Does this album have any tracks registered for it?